# How to pack all loose objects in Git?

Tags: git

I have a bare git repository with some loose objects. How do I pack all loose obects into a single, new pack, without changing other packs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could come up with:

```
$ git prune-packed
$ find objects/?? -type f | perl -pe 's@^objects/(..)/@$1@' |
  git pack-objects objects/pack/pack
$ git prune-packed
```

Is there anything simpler?

Answer (score 3):

`git pack-objects < object_list.txt`

where object_list.txt has a list of object hashes, delimited by '\n'.

[git-pack-objects](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-objects.html)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it was useful for me to solve the problem. I can't accept, because it doesn't solve the problem end-to-end.

Answer (score 0):

Warning, when using [`git prune-packed`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune-packed).

Before Git 2.22 (Q1 2019), "`git prune-packed`" did not notice and complain against excess
arguments given from the command line, which now it does.

See [commit 9b0bd87](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b0bd87ed2ae444fa0ecf55ba497e666b3911fbb) (11 Feb 2019) by [Ramsay Jones (`jeffhostetler`)](https://github.com/jeffhostetler).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ebf846c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ebf846c0086114714c0162c4dc8acbf344740c1d), 07 Mar 2019)</sup>

It will now display "`too many arguments`" if any argument is passed to `git prune-packed`.

Comment: This is nice to know, but it doesn't answer the question.